# Simple cut and paste excel VBA: inconsitent and strange results

Tags: vba, excel

I need to cut and paste a row array of non-empty values in an Active Sheet. "E5" is the first non-empty cell in the row array I want to cut. This array is just a sequence of numbers from 1:10 with no gaps. The desired behavior is to cut the sequence and past at "F5". The only complication is that I need the range to be copied is not fixed.

Tried:

```
Sub Update()             
     ActiveSheet.Range("E5", Range("5:5").End(xlToRight).Address).Copy
     ActiveSheet.Range("F5").Select
     ActiveSheet.Paste     
End Sub
```

I've had this code work once, or at least the "cut" part. Now, the resulting output for the whole code block is either:

1. Error 1004 or 438
2. Code cuts and pastes 1:2 to "F5"
3. Cuts and pastes 1:1 to "F5"

Please note that before running the macro, I have always made sure that the array to be cut is exactly the same.

What's the proper method?

Truly, I've looked for a solution but all I found were complex or verbose macros. And VBA's structure is kind of opaque at first, at least to me.

Comment: Delete Range("E5", and  .Address) in the first line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

10 mins and no answer? This might me my lucky day :P

Is this what you are trying? I have commented the code so you shouldn't have any problem understanding it.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lCol As Long

    '~~> Set this to the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        '~~> Find the last column which has data in Col 5
        lCol = .Cells(5, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        '~~> Directly cut paste
        .Range(.Cells(5, 5), .Cells(5, lCol)).Cut .Range("F5")
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. Your code seems like it should work consistently. (By the way, just re-ran my own code block and it worked as well... but I can't be sure it'll work again tomorrow.)

Comment: Your code may not work the next time.  And the reason is very simple. The second range object is not fully qualified. Your active sheet and 'Activesheet' may not be the same